# Don't clear cart when checkout

Tags: checkout, orders, quote

I need to keep the products in the cart when checkout, or copy last order quote to current session quote. I tried:

```
$quoteA = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
$quoteB = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

$quoteB->merge($quoteA);

$quoteB->collectTotals()->save();
$quoteB->save();
```

But this not worked, how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the reorder functionality for Magento!

You can build an observer which is triggered after the order is created.

From app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Controller/Abstract.php

```
/**
 * Action for reorder
 */
public function reorderAction()
{
    if (!$this->_loadValidOrder()) {
        return;
    }
    $order = Mage::registry('current_order');

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cartTruncated = false;
    /* @var $cart Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart */

    $items = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        try {
            $cart->addOrderItem($item);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e){
            if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getUseNotice(true)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            }
            else {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/history');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e,
                Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.')
            );
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        }
    }

    $cart->save();
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in file `/home/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Success.php` in lines:

```
/**
     * Get last order ID from session, fetch it and check whether it can be viewed, printed etc
     */
    protected function _prepareLastOrder()
    {
        $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
        if ($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            if ($order->getId()) {
                $isVisible = !in_array($order->getState(),
                    Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getInvisibleOnFrontStates());
                $this->addData(array(
                    'is_order_visible' => $isVisible,
                    'view_order_id' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/view/', array('order_id' => $orderId)),
                    'print_url' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/print', array('order_id'=> $orderId)),
                    'can_print_order' => $isVisible,
                    'can_view_order'  => Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $isVisible,
                    'order_id'  => $order->getIncrementId(),
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

and in the file `core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/config.php` , here is setup the calls functions of visible/invisible, i believe with that you make this successfully.

Comment: The first file is a block, and is setting order configuration, the second file is about order status... this will not solve my problem...